# How to list Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a WordPress taxonomy, and I was wondering if there's anyway to list the taxonomy like:

```
                       <ul id="portfolioFilter">
                           <li class="filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
                           <li class="filter" data-filter="category1">Image Slider</li>
                           <li class="filter" data-filter="category2">Youtube</li>
                           <li class="filter" data-filter="category3">Vimeo</li>
                           <li class="filter" data-filter="category4">Lightbox Photos</li>
                           <li class="filter" data-filter="category5">Lightbox Video</li>
                       </ul>
```

Yup, there should not be any  links, but Class filter in it data-filter with the term name. Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried already? When asking a question, you should share your research. We're in here to help, not to do the job for you ;)

Comment: And what if I'm completely null about it, lol. I thought it wasn't even possible. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_terms('YOUR-TAXONOMY');
    if ( $terms ) :
?>
<ul id="portfolioFilter">
    <li class="filter" data-filter="all">All</li>
    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ): ?>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```